# Why do we use a pendingIntent to start a GeofenceTransitionIntentService?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-geofence

I was going through the google docs for Geofencing and I have some doubts. They have used a pendingIntent to start the GeofenceTransitionIntentService. Can someone please explain why? Also when is the pendingIntent fired? Is it done when the user enters the geofence or as soon as the pendingIntent is created. Thanks in advance !!

From the android docs and my little understanding of pendingIntent I am not able to understand what is the foreign application here?

> A PendingIntent is a token that you give to a foreign application
>   (e.g. NotificationManager , AlarmManager , Home Screen
>   AppWidgetManager , or other 3rd party applications), which allows the
>   foreign application to use your application's permissions to execute a
>   predefined piece of code.

[Geofencing Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#HandleGeofenceTransitions)

Answer (score 2):

pending intent are not immediate, that's why why its called pending. just as in this paragraph.

> A PendingIntent is a token that you give to a foreign application (e.g. NotificationManager , AlarmManager , Home Screen AppWidgetManager , or other 3rd party applications), which allows the foreign application to use your application's permissions to execute a predefined piece of code.

taking the NotificationManager as an example, its an external service or application. when creating a `Notification`  using the `NotificationManager` class you pass a `PendingIntent` which links to an activity(or just say an application), this is the intent that will handle the notification. its just saying that the `pendingIntent` will link to an application that will handle to Notification when clicked.

same thing goes for the Geofencing, pendingIntent is pending(waiting) until an action that will trigger its to call the application that will execute the incoming event or data etc